# Json Dynamic views spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, json-view

I am kind of new to spring MVC
and I wanted to use JasonViews (Jackson) for dynamic JSON per request and I didn't want to change my controllers too much .. so @marty here gave me a great solution in his blog

http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/custom-json-views-with-spring-mvc-and-jackson/

The problem is that I need control over the HTTP status codes,so my controllers are returning types of HttpResponse{T} and not List{T} how can I customize the code in order to support parsing of types like HttpResponse{List{Book}}?

If not possible, can I control the Http status code without the HttpResponse?

Answer (score 0):

I may need to see an example of your code to really understand what you are asking, but this *might* point you in the right direction:

Take @marty's code and try extending HttpEntityMethodProcessor with it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/HttpEntityMethodProcessor.htmlS

Then, you need to make your method signatures look like

```
public ResponseEntity<MyType> getMyTypeWithControlOverResponseEntity(...) {...}
```

You can find more info on this signature type at:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-httpentity

Let me know if this is not the right direction you were trying to go or need more help. =)